# Unsual Firewall Traffic from Phone and Messaging Storage Group

Tags: security, privacy, data-monitoring, phone-app, firewall

I'm using Rethink DNS to monitor traffic.

I'm curious as to why the 'Phone and Messaging Storage' group would be reaching out to google domains in addition to app.hubspot.com.

Attached are the firewall logs along with the apps included within the 'Phone and Messaging Storage' group.
[image: UnusualTraffic]
[image: PhoneAndMessaging]